# Swift NSNotificationCenter observer in class extension crash

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, nsnotificationcenter

I tried to create a universal mechanism that could react to keyboard showing and hiding in iOS. I came up with simple protocol and its extension that doesn't contain real animations but pulls them from object that adopts this protocol:

```
import UIKit

protocol KeyboardAnimatable {
    func keyboardWillShowAnimation() -> (() -> Void)?
    func keyboardWillHideAnimation() -> (() -> Void)?
}

extension KeyboardAnimatable where Self: UIViewController {

    func setupKeyboardNotifcationListeners() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func removeKeyboardNotificationListeners() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        let animationDuration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSTimeInterval
        let animationCurve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]!.intValue
        let curveAnimationOption = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(animationCurve))
        let options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.BeginFromCurrentState, curveAnimationOption]

        if let animation = keyboardWillShowAnimation() {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: 0, options: options, animations: animation, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        let animationDuration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSTimeInterval
        let animationCurve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]!.intValue
        let curveAnimationOption = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(animationCurve))
        let options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.BeginFromCurrentState, curveAnimationOption]

        if let animation = keyboardWillHideAnimation() {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, delay: 0, options: options, animations: animation, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

I explicitly use `where` clause in `extension KeyboardAnimatable where Self: UIViewController` to narrow it down so that I can use `self` when adding observers.
Now I can create a view controller that adopts this protocol and e.g. changes constraint when keyboard shows up:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, KeyboardAnimatable {

    @IBOutlet weak var constraintYCenter: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupKeyboardNotifcationListeners()
    }

    func keyboardWillShowAnimation() -> (() -> Void)? {
        return {
            self.constraintYCenter.constant = 100
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHideAnimation() -> (() -> Void)? {
        return nil
    }

//    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
//        print("will show")
//    }
//    
//    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
//        print("will hide")
//    }

    deinit {
        removeKeyboardNotificationListeners()
    }
}
```

But when I run this code the app crashes with following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[KeyboardAnimatableDemo.ViewController keyboardWillShow:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb429f192d0'
```

It looks like my view controller doesn't use `keyboardWillShow:` method implemented in protocol extension.
When I uncomment these two methods implemented directly in `ViewController` they work (logs are printed) but then whole concept with common keyboard animator is useless.

I thought there might be something weird happening with `self` in `setupKeyboardNotifcationListeners()` but even if I change it to e.g. `func setupKeyboardNotifcationListeners(vc: UIViewController)` and use `vc` instead of `self` when registering observer nothing changes.

One possible solution could be also creating UIViewController extension only for a subset of controllers that adopt this protocol e.g. something like this `extension UIViewcontroller where Self: KeyboardAnimatable` but this one doesn't compile and I haven't found any example of such definition so it may even not be possible in Swift.

Did anyone try to achieve something similar and he succeeded?

Comment: Decomment the lines with `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide` declaration as you are trying to call those functions

Comment: But I want to use methods implemented in extension, otherwise I won't gain anything if I have to implement these methods in each UIViewController.

Comment: Right, i skipped the declaration in your protocol extension

Comment: Have you tried to use closures as notification handlers (with `addObserverForName(_:object:queue:usingBlock:` )? It can be harder to remove observers this way, but I think you can store observers as properties and remove them in `deinit` method.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing protocol and introducing "empty" implementation for those methods. Now `Extension` for keyboard extends directly UIViewController so it should be quite easy to use.

Code is on gist: https://gist.github.com/AdamSliwakowski/6fa1e920254ce584d203